# Version of Hibernate and MySQL to be used in Eclipse Mars

Tags: mysql, eclipse, hibernate

Can anyone suggest which version of Hibernate and MySQL connector I should be using to run a Hibernate application?

I am using MySQL 5.5 and Eclipse Mars

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would use a build manager in order to simplify your project setup, like Maven. And if you do, you then would go to a Maven repository and check all available versions and you would choose the version you need, for example:

[Maven MySQL connector repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java)
[Hibernate Maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core)

If you do so, Maven will take care downloading all the necessary dependencies that you will specify in pom.xml

Even if you don't want to use Maven, you can check Maven repositories to verify all available versions, you would download them and try for yourself if those versions suit your desired setup and needs.